# How do I remove all hyphens with a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I thought this would have done it...

```
$rowfetch = $DBS->{Row}->GetCharValue("meetdays");
$rowfetch = /[-]/gi;
printline($rowfetch);
```

But it seems that I'm missing a small yet critical piece of the regex syntax.

`$rowfetch` is always something along the lines of:

```
------S
-M-W---
--T-TF-
```

etc... to represent the days of the week a meeting happens

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$rowfetch =~ s/-//gi
```

That's what you need for your second line there.  You're just finding stuff, not actually changing it without the "s" prefix.

You also need to use the regex operator "=~" for this.

Comment: Thanks... thats what I thought... Just wasnt sure how to reassign it... Any way to do it in one line?

Comment: Easier said than done regarding "one line"... I've never found a "pure" way of running a regular expression replace.

Comment: Use the 's' option for multiple lines s/-//gis

Comment: So this regular expression says 'store into $rowfetch the characters that are not matched by the regular expression "s/-//gi" ' ?

Comment: Not quite.
The regular expression says "replace $rowfetch with all occurrences of the first set "-" replaced with the second set ""... thus deleting the hyphen."

Comment: @codelogic: the 's' modifier is irrelevant here.  It lets the '.' (dot) match every character including line separators (\n, \r, etc.), but there are no dots in this regex.

Comment: @cmartin - makes more sense.. thanks... that actually helped me put a large part of regex into perspective - there are two groups /(1)/(2)/ .. s means search expression set (1) and convert to expression set (2)?

Answer (score 7):

Here is what your code presently does:

```
# Assign 'rowfetch' to the value fetched from:
#      The function 'GetCharValue' which is a method of: 
#         An Value in A Hash Identified by the key "Row" in:
#          Either a Hash-Ref or a Blessed Hash-Ref
#      Where 'GetCharValue' is given the parameter "meetdays"
$rowfetch = $DBS->{Row}->GetCharValue("meetdays");
# Assign $rowfetch to the number of times 
#  the default variable ( $_ ) matched the expression /[-]/ 
$rowfetch = /[-]/gi;
#  Print the number of times. 
printline($rowfetch);
```

Which is equivalent to having written the following code:

```
$rowfetch = ( $_ =~ /[-]/ ) 
printline( $rowfetch );
```

The magic you are looking for is the

```
=~
```

Token instead of

```
=
```

The former is a Regex operator, and the latter is an assignment operator.

There are many different regex operators too:

```
if( $subject =~ m/expression/  ){
}
```

Will make the given codeblock execute only if $subject matches the given expression, and

```
$subject =~ s/foo/bar/gi
```

Replaces ( `s/`) all instances of "foo" with "bar", case-insentitively (`/i`), and repeating the replacement more than once(`/g`), on the variable `$subject`.

Answer (score 6):

Using the [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#tr%2fSEARCHLIST%2fREPLACEMENTLIST%2fcds) operator is faster than using a `s///` regex substitution.

```
$rowfetch =~ tr/-//d;
```

Benchmark:

```
use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);

my $s = 'foo-bar-baz-blee-goo-glab-blech';

cmpthese(-5, {
  trd => sub { (my $a = $s) =~ tr/-//d },
  sub => sub { (my $a = $s) =~ s/-//g },
});
```

Results on my system:

```
         Rate  sub  trd
sub  300754/s   -- -79%
trd 1429005/s 375%   --
```

Answer (score 2):

Off-topic, but without the hyphens, how will you know whether a "T" is Tuesday or Thursday?

Comment: Thursday is R.. I just put that data up there so people would know what I was talking about in a general sense.